# How to access WCF in a IIS using a .Net Standard class

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0

I built a WCF component resident in IIS. I have tested it and it appears to work correctly, however I'm trying to access it via the .NET `Standard` Class without success.

Could someone exemplify how we are expected to set C# commands to access the WCF methods?

The Visual Studio 2017 'Add Connected Service' dialogue with C# was used in a .NET Standard 2.0 Class.

**Further detail**

In `reference.cs` file there is

```
public interface IAvisaWCF
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IAvisaWCF/DoAccess", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IAvisaWCF/DoAccessResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task DoAccessAsync(string INT_IdFisico, int INT_Id, int DI_ID, string DI_IDFisico, char Numero_Leitor, string Mobile_EMEI);

public partial class AvisaWCFClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<AvisaWCFRef.IAvisaWCF>, AvisaWCFRef.IAvisaWCF
{

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task DoAccessAsync(string INT_IdFisico, int INT_Id, int DI_ID, string DI_IDFisico, char Numero_Leitor, string Mobile_EMEI)
    {
        return base.Channel.DoAccessAsync(INT_IdFisico, INT_Id, DI_ID, DI_IDFisico, Numero_Leitor, Mobile_EMEI);
    }
```

In the Net Standard Class (stantiated in a Android Class) I had instantiated the component and Called de Async Method,  like this;

```
    AvisaWCFRef.AvisaWCFClient oComp = new AvisaWCFRef.AvisaWCFClient();

oComp.DoAccessAsync(Int_IdFisico, Int_Id, DI_ID, DI_IdFisico, Numero_Leitor, Mobile_EMEI);
```

The system then gave me the following error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 [[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version = 2.0.5.0,
>   Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35]]:
>   An error occurred during deserialization of the request message body for the DoAccess operation.
>   The OperationFormatter encountered an invalid message body.
>   It was hoped to find 'Element' node with name 'DoAccess' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'.
>   Found element node with name 'DoAccessAsync' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' occurred

Could someone exemplify how I'm supposed to set C# commands to access the WCF methods?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf